# How to use functions that use and return objects from a .dll in Java code?

Tags: java, c++, dll

I need to use an API that consists of .dll and .h files. within Java code.
I found that I can use JNI to load and access .dll files, but I'm new at JNI and i don't know much of c++ and .dll and it seams kinda difficult.
What I need is to call functions (that return or use C++ objects/classes) from those .dll files and I want to know if there are java libraries that make this process easier.
I would be great if someone could provide links to some examples or tutorials that show in detail how to call different functions form .dll files.

EDIT:

Ok, so basically I only have a .dll library (and not a .so file or the source code, for linux). Is there a way to make java load .dll files ? For example: can java runtime for windows be installed and run with wine on a Linux system? And so, will that determine java to load the .dll file for that library ?

Answer (score 3):

JNA is supposed to make this easier.

https://github.com/twall/jna

Comment: Yup.  JNA is the way to go, IMHO.

Comment: I also found this library. Seams pretty cool. One question: does it have platform specific issues ? Example: if i create a java app that loads a .dll and uses its functions, will it run on windows and linux ? If not, what are the constraints or will wine help me with that?

Comment: I haven't used it. It looks like it works cross-platform. I think if you're trying to call a DLL on linux via WINE with this you're entering muddy waters. I don't know enough of how WINE works to know if this might work or not. Better research that part.

Comment: Well, if the .dll library does't use windows specific calls, everything  should be ok right ?

Comment: You point WINE at an exe, not a DLL. You'll have to run java.exe with wine. I doubt that would work since the JVM is so complex. You could probably make an exe that calls the DLL that you run with WINE and get Java to call that. I've done that and it works pretty well.

Comment: Is there not a linux version of this library available? In that case JNA will call the appropriate library on each platform.

Comment: I tested the .dll loading on Windows and it worked fine. But when i tried the same code on linux, i got the message "Unable to load library 'MAPI': libMAPI.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". Why does it need a .so file ? and can i generate it somehow ?

Comment: A .so file is on linux what a DLL is on Windows. No, you can't generate one from the other. You have to compile from source. You're trying to use MAPI? I doubt WINE has the infrastructure that the MAPI DLL depends on. Use Java Mail to send e-mail.

Comment: Sorry, the "MAPI" name is just a test name (should be MyAPI.dll). Actually the api that I need to use consists only of .dll and .h files, so my actual question is: can .dll files be loaded in Java in Linux OS in any?

Comment: No, I don't think so. If you have the source port the library to Linux. If you don't, make an exe that uses the DLL and then run the exe using WINE.

Comment: Hmmm... but can a java runtime for windows be installed and run with wine on a Linux ? (thus, running the java code with the jvm for windows )